# Array not returning an answer in For loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array that takes in values from a single row of a spreadsheet (1 row, 185 columns). I then want to loop through the array, looking for a match between the values in the array, and values in a particular cell.

However, every time I run the code, it says it finds a match, but does not return a value to the cell.

The relevant lines of the code are:

```
Dim qCountry()

Worksheets("Data").Activate

    qCountry = Range("A1:GC1").Value
```

```
    For i = 1 To 185
          If Cells(aRow, bCol) <> vbNullString Then
              Exit For
          ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(aRow, 4), "*" & qCountry(i) & "*") = 1 Then
              Cells(aRow, bCol) = qCountry(i)
          End If
    Next i
```

A screenshot of my array:

[image: Array]

Comment: shouldn't `<> vbNullString` be `= vbNullString` ?

Comment: `Cells(aRow, bCol).value = qCountry(i)`

Comment: I would try: `Cells(aRow, bCol).Value = qCountry(i,1)` and also `qCountry = Application.Transpose(Range("A14:GC14").Value)`

Comment: @Slai it is meant to be ````<>vbNullString```` as I don't need to conduct the check if the cell already has a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define `qCountry` as a normal `Variant` variable, like this:

```
Dim qCountry as Variant
```

This will get rid of one extra dimension, but you still have a multi-dimension array.

---

If you want to deal with an **array of single dimension**, you can use the `Application.Transpose()` **Function**:

```
qCountry = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:GC1").Value)
```

But since you have data in a **row**, you need to do it twice:

```
qCountry = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:GC1").Value))
```

At this point your code will work:

```
Dim qCountry
Worksheets("Data").Activate
qCountry = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:GC1").Value))

For i = 1 To 185
      If Cells(aRow, bCol) <> vbNullString Then
          Exit For
      ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(aRow, 4), "*" & qCountry(i) & "*") = 1 Then
          Cells(aRow, bCol) = qCountry(i)
      End If
Next i
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Values can be accessed as shown in the screenshot :

```
Cells(aRow, bCol) = qCountry(1, i)
```